# What does this lambda–sigma notation mean?

Tags: notation

I am currently reading the CRC Handbook of Phosphorus-31 Nuclear Magnetic Resonance Data by John C. Tebby (CRC Press, 1991) and on several figures (ex. pages 9 to 14) there is a caption that reads along these lines

> $\ce{^{31}P}$ NMR chemical shifts of three coordinate (λ3 σ3) phosphorus compounds. (Tables B to E.)

What does the (λ3 σ3) signify? I've not seen that notation before, and it is on the captions of some of the charts I need.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The notation refers to the valency (number of valence electrons involved in bonds, i.e., either 3 or 5) and coordination number (number of substituents attached) in [organophosphorus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organophosphorus_compounds) compounds. For example, it could refer to the tautomeric forms of phosphonate esters:<sup>1</sup>

[image: Tautomers of phosphonate esters]

So the λ<sup>3</sup>σ<sup>3</sup> refers to a P with 3 bonding valence electrons (the lone pair doesn't count) and 3 substituents attached while λ<sup>5</sup>σ<sup>4</sup> refers to a P with all five of its valence electrons involved in bonds and 4 substituents attached.

---

*Reference*

1. Kraszewski, A.; Stawinski, J. H-Phosphonates: Versatile synthetic precursors to biologically active phosphorus compounds. *Pure Appl. Chem.* **2009,** *79* (12), 2217–2227. [DOI: 10.1351/pac200779122217](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200779122217).

Answer (score 7):

To add to the currently accepted answer, this is what I found from IUPAC publications.

In [*Treatment of Variable Valence in Organic Nomenclature (Lambda Convention) (IUPAC Recommendations 1983)*](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac198456060769):

> These recommendations, designated by Lm (lambda), provide a general method for indicating nonstandard valence states of formally neutral skeletal atoms in parent hydrides.
>
> The *bonding number*, $n$, of a skeletal atom in a parent hydride is the sum of the total number of valence bonds to adjacent skeletal atoms, if any, and the number of attached hydrogen atoms.
>
> A *nonstandard bonding number* of a *neutral* skeletal atom in a *parent hydride* is indicated by the symbol λ<sup>*n*</sup>. [...] Derivatives formed by substitution of hydrogen atoms of the parent hydride are named by means of prefixes and/or suffixes in the established manner.

Regarding the sigma notation, it seems to have been included in a tentative draft of *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry*, dating from 1973. However, it was omitted from the eventual 1979 publication for the following reason (taken from the same source above):

> In the first publication of the provisional Section D rules, the symbol σ<sup>*m*</sup>, where $m$ is the number of σ bonds terminating at the heteroatom, was suggested either as an alternative to or in conjunction with the λ<sup>*n*</sup> symbol. However, the number of hydrogen atoms attached to the heteroatom would have to be included in this symbolism for a parent hydride, which is not consistent with the basic principles of substitutive nomenclature. In organic nomenclature, implied (or expressed) valence requirements of a skeletal atom in a parent hydride are satisfied with hydrogen atoms *after* other structural requirements are met. Hence, this symbolism was not included in the revision of the Section D rules for the 1979 edition of the IUPAC Organic Rules.