# Calculate the valence of Fe2O3

Tags: electronic-configuration, valence

$$\ce{FeO}$$

Is called "Iron(II) oxide ".

$$\ce{Fe_2O_3}$$

Is called "Iron(III) oxide ".

The number in the parenthesis is "Valence" of the substance. Frankly, I don't know how to calculate such number. Can you explain to me, with this example, how come $\ce{FeO}$ has valence $2$ and the other one has valence $3$?

The only thing I know how to do is calculate the electron configurations of each element.

For Iron, it is $1s^22s^22p^63s^23p^64s^23d^6$.

For Oxygen, it is $1s^22s^22p^4$.

I am told that based on the electron configuration you can get the valence of each element. And then, you can calculate the valence of $\ce{FeO}$ and $\ce{Fe_2O_3}$. **But how?**

---

I made a question before [Calculating valence of oxides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32996/calculating-valence-of-oxides), but it was wrongly formulated (they corrected me on the definition of Valence, but turns out what I actually need was *how* to calculate it), so I'm flagging it to be closed.

---

**Edit** The question [How to get the valencies of elements?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4547/how-to-get-the-valencies-of-elements) doesn't explain how to calculate the valence of a **combination** of two elements.

Comment: @Jan hm, but it doesn't explain how to calculate the combination of two elements. I can tell the valence of $Fe$ and $O$, but what of $Fe_2O_3$?

Comment: It's not the combination that has a valency, it is each element in the compound. $\ce{O}$ can always be considered to be divalent. $\ce{Fe}$ can assume multiple valencies, which is what the (II) and the (III) signify.

Comment: somewhat related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8336/why-can-some-ions-have-different-valence

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/539/what-does-this-notation-mean

Comment: And if you'd want to predict http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19900/find-the-valences-of-z-26

Comment: @Mithoron neither link will explain how to calculate valency when two elements are involved (like $\ce{FeO}$ or $\ce{Fe_2O_3}$).

Comment: I'll try to write an answer but for example you know what bonds are?

Comment: But well - this question should be closed as you're asking about the same thing, and you even got quite nice answer

Answer (score 1):

@Voldemort you learn the valencies rather than calculate them.  Valency is a fact of experiment whilst electron configuration gives an underlying explanation for the observations from experiment.

Iron has two different valencies (and oxidation states) which are a consequence of the stability of the electron configuration that remains when electrons are lost upon reaction.  So, iron can loose 2 electrons to leave a stable $\ce{Fe++}$ species; in your reaction those 2 electrons are gained by oxygen to give an anion that has 8 electrons in its outer shell which is a stable configuration.

Iron can also loose 3 electrons to leave a stable system and again, in your system, the electrons are picked up by the appropriate number of oxygen atoms to give oxygen anions that have 8 electrons in their outer shell.

If you look at the either side of the periodic table, say sodium reacting with a halogen, say chlorine (to give sodium chloride); you can see the 8 electron rule working.  But you're looking at a system where the iron is found in the middle of the periodic table and is a lot more difficult to predict when compared to the 8 electron rule.

Comment: So basically valencies can't be calculated and therefore the only way to know that $\ce{Fe_2O_3}$ is "Iron (III) Oxide" is with memory?

Comment: @Voldemort yes.  But they can be explained and they can be guessed at with some certainty.  The alkali metals should have a valency of 1 since that outer electron is going to be easy to loose and the remaining cation has a stable 8 electron shell.  The halogens when reacting with alkali metals should also have a valency of 1 but this isn't always the case.  As for the d-block elements, these can be a bit more difficult.

Comment: @Voldemort I'm afraid your question is so terribly basic that user1945827 is overestimating it - do you want to get valence when you already know chemical formula? He's talking about predicting from configuration but if you have the formula you don't have to predict anything

Comment: @Mithoron by chemical formula you mean $\ce{FeO}$ and $\ce{Fe_2O_3}$? Then yes, I only want to know how to calculate their valence. So there is indeed a way to calculate it?

Comment: Useful links https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_structure, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_%28chemistry%29

Comment: @Voldemort Yes that's what I mean. I'll search if there wasn't such question earlier

Comment: From \ce{FeO}, I'd guess iron has a 2+ charge, so neutral iron must have lost 2 electrons. While valence electrons are easiest to lose, I'd deduce that the valency of \ce{FeO} is 2.